# How to ensure that message transmission is reliable - ASB

Tags: azure, domain-driven-design, messaging, azureservicebus

I am using Azure Service Bus to implement message communication between separate bounded contexts. I am curious about what techniques people use to ensure that domain events raised in one bc are guaranteed to be received by another consuming bc.

For example, say the "orders" bc raises an "orderPlaced" event, how can I ensure that this event is received by a "shipping" bc. I understand that 2 phase commit is not advisable in cloud, so what is the alternative? How do I mitigate against the order being placed, but the message failing to be sent to the service bus in the event of a network failure?

Thoughts would be welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you send a BrokeredMessage to a Service Bus Queue and receive an acknowledgement, the message has been successfully stored in the queue. You don't have to worry about the message dying in transit due to a network error after you've been told it is persisted.

What you *can* worry about is a Service Bus Queue falling offline for a period of time and being unavailable. During an outage, your orderPlaced message wouldn't be able to get into the queue in the first place, and your shipping logic wouldn't be able to receive orders that are already persisted in your queue.

Note that Service Bus Queue outages are transient and the Queue recovers and returns to normal service. At that time, your shipping app could drain the queue of existing messages, and your ordering app could once again insert orderPlaced messages. I don't actually recall the last time I've seen one of my Service Bus Queues go down - it's a rare event.

If you are super-concerned about never ever ever EVER dropping a message, look at [paired namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-paired-namespaces). Basically, this allows for failover to standby queues so that you can insert messages while your primary is down. Automatic detection checks to see when your primary queue comes back online. And a siphon process sucks messages that were inserted into the failover queue during the outage back into the primary once the primary comes back online.

*Edit:* When sending, there is still the chance that even though you *had* a valid Service Bus Queue connection in your QueueClient or MessagingFactory, the underlying Service Bus Queue just went down like a glass-jawed prizefighter. The vast majority of the time, these errors are transient. To handle them, set the RetryPolicy property of your MessagingFactory or QueueClient. Off the top of my head, I think that the only policy currently available is the RetryExponential policy. This will perform a back-off that will retry sending the message until the specified number of attempts are exhausted. This is the easy-peasy way to handle transient errors that pop up in your Service Bus Queue connection.

Comment: "During an outage, your orderPlaced message wouldn't be able to get into the queue in the first place, and your shipping logic wouldn't be able to receive orders that are already persisted in your queue." - in the case where the message never made it to the queue (because of transient error), how do I ensure the intent to send the message is kept? If I don't do that, surely the message is lost and never makes it to the queue. thx

Comment: @user644698, I updated the answer to talk about the built-in retry policy to handle transient errors that could crop up. Use this with paired namespaces, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Okay, but what happens in a scenario where the order is placed in the order BC and it is committed to the database, but before the message is sent to the service bus the orders BC goes offline. This is a real possibility (particularly if the service bus is offline), but would you generally try and mitigate against it? Thanks again for your posts, they are useful.

Comment: @user644698, paired namespaces coupled with a retry policy should mitigate against not being able to send a message if you set your failoverInterval to zero. This is a good article on the topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-async-messaging. See the "failoverInterval" bullet under the "The MessagingFactory.PairNamespaceAsync API" heading.

Comment: thanks, i'll look into that. I have been looking into the idea of persisting the message in db before sending to message bus. Then a separate process runs to flush the message table. This way I could always guarantee a message gets on the bus. Without that, is there not a possibility, albeit small, that the message did not get on the bus?

Comment: @user644698, if you implement the strategy in the previous comment with paired namespaces, a failover interval set to 0, and a retry policy, there is only an infinitesimally small probability that your message won't make it into the queue. I would suggest that the complexity of implementing a process to flush a database is likely going to give you a greater failure rate due to having more moving parts than the aforementioned strategy.